# ZigZag Function's formula?

Tags: graphing-functions, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm searching the formula/expression of the "zigzag" function that returns the following curve/graph:

$\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

I'm looking for

1. that's trigonometric and
2. that's non-trigonometric

Please help. Hopefully one or both are simple enough (not too complex).

---

Why I'm looking for the above function/graph?
[In this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548693/number-of-meetings-of-2-cars-starting-from-opposite-ends-of-a-road) it struck me to at least confirm which result was correct by drawing the above graph for both the objects and then counting all the point of intersections. Thus, confirming the correct answer. But while going to GeoGebra I realized my ignorance/ineptitude to draw such a graph. Though I think I used to be able to draw/know one.

Comment: Try [this formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Floor/27/02/) to convert the floor to trigonometric functions

Comment: @TymaGaidash thanks, that should work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more commonly known as “triangle wave”:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

(Not to be confused with the “sawtooth wave”.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x-\lfloor x\rfloor&\lfloor x\rfloor\equiv_20\\1+\lfloor x\rfloor-x&\lfloor x\rfloor\equiv_21\end{cases}$$

This is the periodic extension of $x\mapsto|x|$.

A non-piecewise definition would be:

$$f(x)=\frac{1-(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}{2}+(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$$

To get a trigonometric *sharp* zig-zag as drawn you’d need to use a Fourier series or some similar idea. No simple trigonometric function will produce the zigzag shown there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Upvoted but I'm more interested in (I'm not sure if I'm using the correct term) a continuous range function. Like that for $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @InanimateBeing You mean, a function that isn’t piece-wise defined?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Does it have a name?

Comment: @InanimateBeing In my opinion there is absolutely nothing wrong with piecewise definitions. But I’ve edited in a non-piecewise version

Comment: @Peter It is now fixed. On my Desmos it rendered fine so I didn’t notice the mistake

Comment: @InanimateBeing Sorry for deleting, there was a mistake that is now fixed.

Comment: @FShrike Your could simplify $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ [into $\text{frac}(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/FractionalPart/27/01/01/01/)

Answer (score 1):

(1) $$x \mapsto \frac2\pi \arccos \cos \pi x$$

(2) $$x \mapsto 4 \left\vert \frac{x}2 - \left\lfloor \frac{x - 1}2 \right\rfloor \right\vert$$